# Android - More than 80 views - How to increase performance

Tags: android, performance

My activity currently has more than 80 views and now I´m getting the error, that this is (obviously) bad for performance. So, what can I do to increase the performance?

Is it possible to only load the views that are visible on the screen?

These are the views i´ve to repeat over and over again:
http://i.imgur.com/Opc1KEA.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way you're fitting 80 of those on your screen, so as you mentioned, you only want to load the views that are visible on the screen. You need to implement an [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html). Depending on your layout that might possibly be in conjunction with a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), but almost certainly some sort of [layout that subclasses `AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews).

Comment: Do I have to use a custom adapter if I want to use my own layout for the list-items? So that I´m basically creating a layout-file with the above pictured content, implement it into the listview and then fill it with the required data?